# Configure JIRA Trigger Plugin for Jenkins multi branch pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jira, webhooks, jenkins-jira-trigger

I have Jenkins **Mutibranch pipeline**. I want to integrate my Jira with one of multibranch project. I have installed the **JIRA Trigger Plugin** and configured Webhook in Jira. however, when I checked in my Jenkins job it does not show me the B***uild when an issue is updated in JIRA*** but it shows when I go to View Configuration in the particular branch. it allows me to select the ***Build when an issue is updated in JIRA*** but there is no option to save the changes. I know this might be a reason the option is view only. but how can I configure this?

Is anyone configured J**IRA Trigger Plugin with Jenkins mutibranch project** where using Jenkinsfile? and what is the correct way of integrating this?

Should I do some coding in the Jenkins file to get this done?

Comment: Seems no answer from anyone? I'm so confuse of why requirement did not come to anyone else.

Comment: Similar conversation is tracked here: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-58112

Comment: @ceilfors it is raised by me